# DirectX 9 rotate DrawUserPrimatives Pointlist

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, directx-9, point-cloud-library

Does anyone know how to rotate DirectX 9 DrawUserPrimatives Pointlist in C#? My aim is to create a pointcloud and be able to rotate around it. Even better would be to use the mouse to rotate the pointcloud's X, Y, Z.

I don't particularly want to use the Unity library if this can be done without extra libraries

Comment: You should learn Matrix.Translation and matrix.transformation

Comment: Similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390437/c-sharp-directx-sprite-origin

Comment: Thanks Jagadeesh. Would that Matrix.Translation and matrix.transformation go into the OnDeviceReset function? I need to update the rotation for every degree of 360 degrees. Do you know of any good code examples to manually rotate primitives using the mouse. I have had a really good dig around but found nothing of relevance.